# What does the Jawbone endpoint_error "Not found" mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: web-services, api, oauth-2.0, jawbone

I'm working on jawbone, I got the token

- accesstoken
- refreshtoken

When I try to get the basic information on the url :

https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.0/users/@me follow the jawbone api : https://jawbone.com/up/developer/endpoints/user

I received the error :

```
{"data":{},
 "meta":{"message":"Not Found",
         "time":1380614680,
         "error_type":"endpoint_error",
         "error_detail":"Unsupported API version: 1.0",
         "code":404}
}
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: I am tryin to integrate the Jawbone in my application. However after authentication the app is not redirecting to my page? What could be wrong with this ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At the moment the jawbone api works fine ...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem so I ask to the support and here's the answer:

> this error message is a little misleading, it actually means it wasn't
>   able to identify your OAuth token

Did you forget to put the "Authorization: Bearer" in the http header?
I didn't but i still got that error!

Comment: i contacted jawbone they answer : "seems that error will occur when using the incorrect access token" . now i'm checking my funcion again .

Comment: please check your header . now i got the data from jawbone api